# Having an Issue with running gnuplot processes from Java

Tags: java, process, gnuplot, filepath, processbuilder

I'm having some trouble running gnuplot processes from Java. I'm creating a gnuplot script file, and then running it from within a java program. I've tried using both Process Builder and building a precess using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("blah blah..."), and neither have the full capability to work. The funny thing is is that using Runtime to make the process works almost perfectly, as long as the image file I'm creating via gnuplot isn't being saved to a directory without a space in it's name. ProcessBuilder doesn't work at all, however, and gives me the error: "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

It's taken me far too long to figure this stuff out, and so any help would be appreciated.

The code I use is here:

```
File script = new File("Demo.plt");    //Script file that outputs to a PNG file

//This works as long as the script file doesn't output to a png with a space in it's filepath
Process aProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnuplot " + script.toString());
Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
aProcess.waitFor();

//This doesn't work at all
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("gnuplot " + script.toString());
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
```

And I know that the script works if run outside of Java, regardless of the spaces in the output line. I've even tried using '\ ' (the escape character for a space) and that doesn't work either. In fact, here is the code that I use:

```
String graphName = "DemoGraph";
//Isolate the FilePath
String path = script.getPath();
path = path.replace(script.getName(),"");
path = path.replace(File.separator, "\\\\"); //Gets around any parsing errors in filepaths on Windows
path = path.replace(" ", "\\ ");   //Should get around parsing errors with spaces in gnuplot, but it seems to be irrelevant.

scriptFileWriter.write("set output \"" + path + graphName + ".png\"\r\n");
```

It's got to be an issue with java, because the scripts run from the Windows command line, and from the gnuplot command line, and frun being run by double-clicking the

Comment: Do you get an error message from gnuplot?  Are there other symptoms of the problem other than "I don't have a png file in the directory I want when I have spaces in the path-name".

Comment: Also, I don't know Java, but could you print the string `"set output \"" + path + graphName + ".png\"\r\n"` so that we can take a look at exactly what gnuplot is seeing?

Comment: This is the string: 'set output "C:\\Users\\toms\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DRTTPS\\Simulation\ Comparison\\DemoGraph.png"'

I am not getting any error message from Gnuplot that I can see, I'm not sure how to forward it's error stream to standard error so that I can see it.

There are no other symptoms really, other than that it doesn't even create the target file. Other errors I had before had it create a file but not write to it, but this error just doesn't do it.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, but you do have a `scriptFileWriter.write` statement which actually is supposed to plot something after you set the output, correct?

Comment: Another thing you can try is to write the gnuplot script to a regular file (e.g. tmp.gnuplot.script) and then issuing a system command to execute "gnuplot tmp.gnuplot.script" and then see if that works.  If not, then you can post the gnuplot script in it's entirety and we can take a look at that.

Comment: The write statement itself doesn't do the plotting, but it is setting up the script to do it.

Comment: I understand that ... I just didn't see a `scriptFileWriter.write('plot ...')` command anywhere.  If you set the terminal, nothing happens until you actually issue a plot command.

Comment: Oh yeah, I left pout the plot command on purpose.

Comment: One last question -- (maybe to show my ignorance of java) -- What happens if you do: `Process aProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnuplot Demo.plt");`  (I'm assuming that's what the scriptFileWriter is writing to).

Comment: Oh yeah, I left pout the plot command on purpose.

However, and I thank you for your help, I found my problem. If you draw your attention to the line: Process aProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnuplot " + script.toString()); 
you'll notice that if any spaces occur in the file path, what windows is actually seeing is:

gnuplut C:\path\to\file with\spaces\in\name

Windows was seeing two arguments. I forgot to put quotes around the file name.

It was a STUPID error. Thanks for your attention though!

Comment: That would have worked, actually, following the logic of what the actual problem was.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accept my own answer for a nother 48 hours. This site is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to put quotes around the file name. It was a STUPID error.